# Подобие memo в Android.

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать метод ввода, наподобие как в memo (кто знаком с Delphi, там было такое текстовое поле), чтобы ввод происходил с верхней строчки. Порылся в настройках `EditText`, там есть увеличение количества линий, но по-прежнему строковый ввод происходит по центру.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @tim_taller, не забудьте принять ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выравнивание текста сверху и слева в EditText:

```
android:lines="5"
android:gravity="left|top"
```

Манифест можно и не трогать.

Comment: Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: android:singleLine="false" - можно не указывать, т.к. в данном случае и так будет false.

Comment: @redsky, в данном случае как я понимаю этот атрибут еще и `deprecated`

Comment: @Dex, как-то так.
В описании EdiText: setSingleLine - ... if false, restores these to the DEFAULT conditions.
в описании TextView: android:singleLine - ... Note: for editable text views, it is better to control this using the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute.

Answer (score 1):

В ресурсах `layout` (или в коде) установите следующий атрибут для поля:

```
android:gravity="top"

<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top"
        android:singleLine="false" android:lines="5"
        />
```